# Input text se posiciona por encima de header con position: fixed

Tags: html, jquery, css

Tengo unos knobs input type text readonly de la librería jquery knob, el tema está en que el texto de estos knob se superposiciona encima de mi header con position: fixed, a que se debe? Cómo puedo solucionarlo? Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
header{
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: auto;
    background: #34495E;
}
```

Los knob no tienen ningún estilo definido en css solo unos div que tengo para recojerlos y alinearlos al centro

```
<center>    
    <div class="pmBox" id="fila1"><center><p class="caja-titulo">PM 1:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $pm1;?>  µg/m<sup>3</sup></p></center><center><input type="text" value="<?php echo $pm1;?>" class="dial" id="circle" readonly="readonly"></center></div>
    
    
    <div class="pmBox" id="fila1"><center><p class="caja-titulo">PM 2.5:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $pm25;?>   µg/m<sup>3</sup></p></center><center><input type="text" value="<?php echo $pm25;?>" class="dial" id="circle" readonly="readonly"></center></div>
</center>

    <br>
<center>
    <div class="pmBox" id="fila2"><center><p class="caja-titulo">PM 4:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $pm4;?>   µg/m<sup>3</sup></p></center><center><input type="text" value="<?php echo $pm4;?>" class="dial" id="circle" readonly="readonly"></center></div>
    
    
    <div class="pmBox" id="fila2"><center><p class="caja-titulo">PM 10:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $pm10;?>   µg/m<sup>3</sup></p></center><center><input type="text" value="<?php echo $pm10;?>" class="dial" id="circle" readonly="readonly"></center></div>
    
</center>
```

Estos son los div

```
#fila1{
    
    vertical-align: middle;
    display:inline-block;
    
}

#fila2{
    
    vertical-align: middle;
    display:inline-block;
    
}
```

Así dibujo los knob

```
$('.dial').knob({
  'min': 0,
  'max': 50,
  'width': 250,
  'height': 250,
  'angleOffset': 260,
  'angleArc': 200,
  'inputColor': "#666666",
  'draw': function() {
    let v = parseInt(this.i[0].value);
    if (v <= 20) this.o.fgColor = '#59BD05'; 
    else if (v <= 35) this.o.fgColor = '#FE9D08'; 
    else this.o.fgColor = '#F33A08'; 
  }
});
```

Comment: Proba poniendole al `header` y al `menu` un [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) alto, por ejemplo, `z-index: 1000px`

Comment: y si haces <div> dentro del header? a modo de containers

Comment: gracias, con el z-index:1 y 2 para cada elemento se solucionó